# Order by splitted string C# and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database table like this:

```
## Settings ##
ID (string)
Value (string)
```

The ID is a string like this Area.Category.SettingName.
I'm trying to build a menu structure based on the ID's, so I would like it to be presented like this.

```
- Area
-- Category
--- SettingName
```

Data could be like this:

```
AreaOne.CategoryOne.MySetting
AreaOne.CategoryOne.MySecondSetting
AreaTwo.CategoryOne.MySetting
...
```

So to do this I tried to get all level one settings, and I tried that using this code:

```
List<Settings> settings = settings.GroupBy(x => x.ID.Split('.')[0]).FirstOrDefault().ToList()
```

And expected this result:

```
AreaOne
AreaTwo
```

But got this result:

```
AreaOne
AreaOne
AreaTwo
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the level one settings, the correct query would be

```
var delimiter = new[] {'.'};
settings.Select(x => x.ID.Split(delimiter, 2)[0]).Distinct().ToList()
```

This cuts off the L1 setting from each row and uses `Distinct` to make sure you only get each of them back once. There's no need to use `GroupBy` unless you want to get aggregate information about each L1 setting (for example, if you want to get full information back from the database but grouped on L1 setting name because it's convenient for some reason).

I also used the overload of `Split` that takes a "limit" parameter because there's no point in doing work that you are going to throw away.

Finally, using a combination of `FirstIndexOf` and `Substring` would be even better performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks Jon, works like it should, no need for the full class back, only the string, so it is perfect.

Comment: I tried adding a "limit" but got this error: ´Cannot convert from 'int' to 'char'´

Comment: @Martin: Guilty of not paying enough attention. If you want a limit, `Split` forces you to give the delimiters as an array. Edited the answer to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a '.Distinct()' , or recoding to do

```
var result = settings.Select(s => x.ID.Split('.')[0]).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to eliminate duplicate entries from your result list. There are three inputs so you are going to get three outputs:

Something like the following should return only one of each:

```
settings.Select(x => x.ID.Split('.')[0]).Distinct().ToList()
```